# Android : Process has died / AsyncTask HTTP get

Tags: android, http, process, android-asynctask

I have a strange problem.
I am downloading some images using AsyncTask.

And sometimes my app silently "crash"

```
I/System.out(28632): Downloaded :  135443
D/szipinf (28632): Initializing inflate state
I/ActivityManager( 1740): Process com.zibi.hypercolor.next (pid 28632) has died.
E/InputDispatcher( 1740): channel '4056a838 com.zibi.hypercolor.next/com.zibi.hypercolor.next.WallpaperSettingsList (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
E/InputDispatcher( 1740): channel '4056a838 com.zibi.hypercolor.next/com.zibi.hypercolor.next.WallpaperSettingsList 
(server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

I/ActivityManager( 1740): Low Memory: No more background processes.
```

Comment: Are you doing some further processing with the images?

Comment: Looks like your app is killed by the android system due to low memory. Are all your images loaded into memory when they are downloaded?

Comment: no they are only downloaded and saved on sdcard or internal storage, i think that if there was an memory low problem it would throw out of memory exceptio

Comment: @zzz that is not the case, actually android kills your app silently if there is low memory issue. you can use DDMS and see how much memory you're using and/or your app has memory leak or not. My guess is that you're getting this error because of memory leak.

Comment: why it isnt killing any of my other apps silenty, only this one? when i simply load too much bitmaps into memory its always throwing out of memory error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Low Memory: No more background processes` is a dead giveaway in your case. The device ran out of memory. When it does, it stops processes. It stops them in following order:

1. Processes without any activity or service, i.e. applications that were put on background and stay running in case the user will need them again.
2. Processes with background services like checking email.
3. Processes with foreground services like background download or playing music player.
4. Processes with foreground activities, i.e. the application being used.

Apparently your application loads too many bitmaps and exhausts all memory. The system first stops everything that is not needed, but when you keep loading bitmaps, it has to kill things that are needed too. The background download service goes first, because it's in the third case above.

You simply have to make sure you never have many bitmaps in memory at the same time. Note, that flash memory is rather fast and using lot of memory slows the device down itself, so it's unlikely that keeping more than the bitmaps on display and a few most recently used ones in memory helps anything.

Comment: There is only one bitmap downloaded and saved on sdcard. But ok, let it be a silent out of memory :)